# Outlook With GMail Over IMAP is Missing All Mail Folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

When I add my Gmail account to Outlook (2013 or 2016), I don't see the `All Mail` folder.

I have found a couple forums suggesting the following steps, but following these steps doesn't solve the problem:

1. Right-click on the root mail folder, and select "IMAP Folders" <- It opens the IMAP folder subscription dialog.
2. Check the box labeled "When displaying hierarchy in Outlook, show only subscribed folders."
3. Query for "All Mail" (case-sensitive)
4. Click on the "All Mail" folder in the results list.
5. Click the subscribe button.
6. Click OK
7. Restart Outlook.

I still don't see `All Mail` folder.  What can I do next?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you try the steps above and still don't see an All Mail folder, manually create one.  Right-click and select "Process Marked Headers" on the context menu, and the folder will populate.

Comment: +1 for an answer that worked and for answering your own question! Side note, this works in Outlook 2016 as well.

Comment: This worked in Outlook 2016 also.

Comment: The `All Mail` folder has to be created under the `[Gmail]`-folder, adjacent to the `Bin`, `Important` and `Spam`-folder.

Comment: Still applicable as of Apr 2020, with the latest Office 365 desktop version. Much appreciated.

Comment: This does not seem to work for Labels. Edit: I see the issue. The new folder in Outlook is created in GMail as INBOX/folder, not just folder, like the existing one. Question is, how to fix that

Comment: Explanation and workaround for labels: https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/gmailroot.htm
I renamed the label "folder" to "INBOX/folder" in GMail (Settings > Labels).

Comment: @Dan, I felt love for about a second when I read your post... all the way from 2013 and still works. Thanks.

Comment: @vicsar I’m glad. It’s perhaps my best contribution to the vast collection of helpful information available via the internet. No matter what else I do in life, at least I have this accomplishment.

Comment: @Dan - I feel you 