# Is there a way to synchronize my entire mailbox from Gmail, to Outlook 2011?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2011

I have a personal GMail account and a second GMail account that is managed by Google Apps.  When I received the second, new mail account about a month ago, I decided to have all of my mail forwarded to my personal GMail account.

After trying to use one email client for work and business, I've decided to try something different, use Outlook for work and GMail for personal.

When I setup my GMail account to sync my work account, I told GMail to archive all of my emails on the Google Apps side.  If I log into the Google Apps GMail page, I have a clean inbox but my archive ('All Mail' folder) is full of all the emails that I've received, and synced to my personal GMail account.

**What I want to do is setup Outlook to download all emails from GMail, including the archived ones? Can this be done?**

Since I've only held this current job for a month, I probably only have about 100-150 emails that I've synced.  It's not a ton, but I would prefer to import them into Outlook so that I can organize them into their appropriate sections.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll want to connect outlook to your goigle apps account using IMAP.

Comment: Thank you.  I've already setup my account and I (should) be able to get new mail.  However, I think I'm not downloading my old messages since they've been archived.

Comment: Outlook has no concept of Gmail Labels.  This means you either need to explain to Outlook the concept ( extensions exist to do this ) or you simply stop using labels.

Comment: You should be seeing an "all mail" IMAP folder in outlook - http://superuser.com/questions/584680/outlook-2013-with-gmail-over-imap-is-missing-all-mail-folder